# Слайдер своими руками на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Нужно придумать как перемещать список с элементами при клике на кнопку `Вперед` и `Назад`.

```
<a href="#" class="next">Вперед</a>
<a href="#" class="prev">Назад</a>
<ul class="list">
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Главное не применять никаких плагинов, например у нас видимые только две буквы из списка, нужно при клике что бы появлялись скрытые а видимые скрывались. Я думал использовать перестановку элементов в списке с начала в конец.

Может есть более эффективное решение....

```
  $('.prev').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     var index = $(".list a").length;

     var elem =  $(".list a:eq("+(index-1)+")");
      var t = elem.text;
          if(!elem.hasClass('not_slide-js')) {
              elem.remove();  // удаляем из конца  
               $('.list').append("<li>"+t+"</li>"); // добавляем в начало
          }

  })
```

Comment: Используйте лучше позиционирование, чем манипуляции с удалением и вставкой в DOM